# How to get the cluster level on Seurat object in R

Tags: r, metadata, cluster-analysis

I want to get a random cluster sample from all clusters made in Seurat object. I have created a Seurat object named glioblastoma. after doing clustering, I got 10 clusters, with levels are 0,1,..., 9. Let's say I have 1000 cells. When I am checking the Idents(glioblastoma) or glioblastoma@active.ident (I also have checked the metadata of the glioblastoma), it will show each cell with each cluster level information, such as cell 1 cluster 0, cell 2 cluster 3, etc. Thus, the length(Idents(glioblastoma)) = 1000 instead of 10. How can I retrieve this information to obtain the cluster level only? Therefore, I can use sample(the number of clusters, 1)? I do not want to make it directly or manually such as sample(0:9, 1) although I know the cluster levels are 0, 1, ..., 9, instead I want to retrieve it for general case when I possibly have cluster levels 0,1,...,11 or 1, 2, ...11 etc. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have no idea what is the question near. If you want a so called unique set of the clusters, it will be `levels(Idents(...))`

Comment: Yes it is what I want. I am not aware with the levels function.